# Why is this error appearing in intelliJ when I go to import from an installed module?

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping, scrape

[Error in IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRRXa.png)

Trying to start a new scraping program and follow a tutorial on youtube, but can't get past this error

[Errors in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdhqY.png)

I have already executed 'pip install requests-html' in command prompt.

Comment: IntelliJ has created a virtual environment called `venv`. Before you did `pip install requests-html` did you activate the virtual environment first?

Comment: Hey Matt. Thank you for your reply. I set the IDE up with a venv yet the error has persisted. I've just downloaded pycharm instead and the error is no longer an issue luckily